# How can I make a Wicket form save radio button state?

Tags: apache, listview, radio-button, wicket, dataview

I want to have a repeater like `DataView` or `ListView`. The first column of each row (named **User ID**) should be read from a `List`, and for each user ID, the program should dynamically create three radio buttons like these:

[image: four columns, "User ID," "Present," "Absent" and "onLeave"; each row displays a user ID and one radio button for each remaining column]

Requirements:

1. The user must able to change selection of radio buttons.
2. When the user clicks the submit button, radio values be displayed using the `info("")` method.

I've already done this by using [this example](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/using-radiogroups.html), but when I click the submit button, old selections are shown, and the form gets reset to those old selections.

Answer (score 1):

This [example code](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/compref/?wicket%3abookmarkablePage=%3aorg.apache.wicket.examples.compref.RadioGroupPage) might be helpful.

Comment: Don! thanks for reply, your answer somehow match with what I want, but instead of one radio button I want to have three radio buttons with each record.

Answer (score 1):

ListView doesn't play very well with form components, but it may work if you call `ListView.setReuseItems(true);`.